# Cannot invoke Radiobutton in Tkinter when using .grid

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I am trying to create a group of Radio buttons in tkinter and I am not able to invoke one after I create them. When I use .pack(), the buttons are able to invoked, but when .grid is used, the buttons cannot be invoked.

```
def initialize():
    Label(window,text = "Customer Name").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    customerName = StringVar()
    nameEntry = Entry(window,textvariable = customerName)
    nameEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    def firstPizza():
        Label(window,text = "Pizza 1").grid(column = 0,row = 1)
        pizzaCost = DoubleVar() #12 and 10
        largeButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Large $15.95",value = 15.95,variable = pizzaCost)
        mediumButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Medium $12.95",value = 12.95, variable = pizzaCost)
        smallButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Small $10.95",value = 10.95, variable = pizzaCost)
        largeButton.grid(column = 0,row = 2)
        largeButton.invoke()
        mediumButton.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        smallButton.grid(column = 2, row = 2)


    firstPizza()
```

This line **largeButton.invoke()** does not perform its intended purpose and nothing is invoked at all.

Comment: 1st question. Why the function in the function? Seams unneeded. 2nd question. What exactly are you expecting `invoke` to do?

Comment: Well in any case. `largeButton.invoke()` is working you are simply using it too soon.

Comment: Im just trying to make sure that the radiobutton is selected when the program is initially run. @Mike-SMT

Comment: How are you getting ```largeButton.invoke()``` to work? I put the line after I grid everything and it still doesn't select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pizzaCost` is a local variable. The invoke works, but then the variable gets garbage-collected and the value gets thrown away.

If you make the variable global, the call to `invoke` will work. Given that you probably want to be able to access the value later, you pretty much have to make it global anyway since you aren't using classes.

In the following example, notice how `pizzaCost` is defined as global inside of `firstPizza`.

```
from tkinter import *
def initialize():
    Label(window,text = "Customer Name").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    customerName = StringVar()
    nameEntry = Entry(window,textvariable = customerName)
    nameEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    def firstPizza():
        global pizzaCost
        Label(window,text = "Pizza 1").grid(column = 0,row = 1)
        pizzaCost = DoubleVar() #12 and 10
        largeButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Large $15.95",value = 15.95,variable = pizzaCost)
        mediumButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Medium $12.95",value = 12.95, variable = pizzaCost)
        smallButton = Radiobutton(window,text = "Small $10.95",value = 10.95, variable = pizzaCost)
        largeButton.grid(column = 0,row = 2)
        largeButton.invoke()
        mediumButton.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        smallButton.grid(column = 2, row = 2)


    firstPizza()

window = Tk()
initialize()
window.mainloop()
```